# Xamarin Camera2 does not save second picture

Tags: xamarin, android-camera2

I use xamarin camera2 api.
my project save photo on same name ( override on one image ).
I set new filename for that but it override on first picture.

```
public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            mFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            mCaptureCallback = new CameraCaptureListener(this);
            mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageAvailableListener(this, mFile);
        }

public void OnClick(View v)
        {
            //button Take photo code :
            if (v.Id == Resource.Id.picture)
            {
                TakePicture();

                mFile = getOutputMediaFile();

            }
        }


private File getOutputMediaFile()
        {
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Activity.GetExternalFilesDir(null), "Pictures");
            if (!mediaStorageDir.Exists())
            {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.Mkdirs())
                {
                    Log.Debug("Pictures", "failed to create Dir");
                    return null;
                }
            }

            
            File mediaFile= new File(mediaStorageDir.Path, "pic.jpg");
            int counter = 1;
            while (mediaFile.Exists())
            {
                mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.Path, "pic" + counter.ToString() + ".jpg");
                counter++;
            }

            return mediaFile;
        }
```

first time : I take a picture it's work and show message : saved image ***path/pic.jpg***

second time : when I take picture it show message : saved image ***path/pic1.jpg*** , but **pic1.jpg** not created and image saved on **pic.jpg**

I use visual studio debugging in `getOutputMediaFile()` **mFile = **pic1.jpg****  but in `ImageAvailableListener` **mFile = pic.jpg**

```
public ImageAvailableListener(Camera2BasicFragment fragment, File file)
        {
            if (fragment == null)
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("fragment");
            if (file == null)
                throw new System.ArgumentNullException("file");

            owner = fragment;
            this.file = file;
        }
```

Comment: please help me!

Comment: I think it's because you create the `ImageAvailableListener` in the `OnActivityCreated` method,at this time,it have save the path `path/pic.jpg`，when you take the second photo,though you call the `getOutputMediaFile()` method and change the mFile,in the `ImageAvailableListener`,it didn't change anymore,so it is still `path/pic.jpg`.

Comment: tnx it resolved. I change name in `ImageSaver`

Comment: Could i post the comment as an accept answer ?